# Flutter Firebase messaging receiving Background notifications Twice

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I am creating a futter app that recives Background and Foreground notifications and when clicking on the notification on the background it should naviagets to LoginPage.dart and when recived while in the foreground it should navigate to LoginPage.dart immediately and I am not sure if this codes recives a notification when the app is terminated

My question is how can i fix this issue my code recives two notifications when in the background one navigates to LoginPage.dart and one doesnt

this is my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:sailerp4/LoginPage.dart';

Future<void> initializeLocalNotifications() async {
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
    iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestAlertPermission: true,
    ),
    macOS: null,
  );

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
}

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  final AndroidNotification? androidNotification = message.notification?.android;
  final DarwinNotificationDetails? iosNotificationDetails = message.notification?.apple != null
      ? DarwinNotificationDetails(
    sound: message.notification!.apple!.sound?.name,
    presentAlert: true,
    presentBadge: true,
    presentSound: true,
  )
      : null;
  final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    android: androidNotification != null
        ? AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channelId',
      'channelName',
      channelDescription: 'channelDescription',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      enableLights: true,
      color: Colors.blue,
    )
        : null,
    iOS: iosNotificationDetails,
    macOS: null,
  );
  await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().show(
    0,
    message.notification?.title ?? '',
    message.notification?.body ?? '',
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: message.data['payload'],
  );
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  //Initialize local notifications
  await initializeLocalNotifications();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SAIL App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'SAIL Emergency Response Notification'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  late final FirebaseMessaging messaging;

  Future<void> requestPermission() async {
    try {
      messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
      final NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: false,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: false,
        criticalAlert: false,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true,
      );
      final token = await messaging.getToken();
      print('this is my token: $token');
      if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
        print('user granted permission');
      }
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
        print('title: ${message.notification?.title} | Body: ${message.notification?.body}');
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0,
          message.notification?.title ?? '',
          message.notification?.body ?? '',
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'channelId',
              'channelName',
              channelDescription: 'channelDescription',
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.high,
              playSound: true,
              enableVibration: true,
              enableLights: true,
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          ),
        );
        firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(message);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error requesting permission: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestPermission();
    Firebase.initializeApp().then((_) {
      requestPermission();
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Handle foreground messages
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage()),
      );
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Handle background messages
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage()),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 32.0),
            Image.asset('assets/images/Sail_logo.png', height: 200.0, width: 250.0,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="SAIL ER"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <meta-data  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried the code without adding this snippet in the initSate()

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Handle foreground messages
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage()),
      );
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Handle background messages
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage()),
      );
    });
```

but the code does not navigates to the LoginPage.dart when reciveing a background notifications and i had problem while trying to call the Navigator.push() the problems i faced are in the BuildContext it kept giving me undefined and not in the same scope and somthing like that

Comment: why ```Firebase.initializeApp()``` is two times in ```main()``` ? have you tried with one time only with await

Comment: I tried and its still the same two notifications @jayeshgurudayalani

Answer (score 0):

change

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Handle foreground messages
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage()),
      );
    });
```

to

```
 FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(
    //push to scr
    },
  );
```

and

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
```

to

```
 flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: _handlePushScreen,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: _handlePushScreen,
    );
```

for firebase notification

- FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen will run when you receive a notification.
- FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() will run when you tap the notification while the app is still in the background.
- FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen will run when you tap the notification when the app is being terminated.

for local notification

- onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse will run when you tap the notification while the app is in the background or terminated.
- onDidReceiveNotificationResponse will run when you tap the notification while the app is in the forceground.